# How do I debug my existing lambdas in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda

I've installed the [AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-vscode#getting-started), logged into my AWS account and I can see a list of my lambdas. But the [instructions for debugging](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-vscode/blob/develop/docs/debugging-python-lambda-functions.md) are very vague:

> Launch Visual Studio Code and open a SAM application or create a new
> one.
>
> Note: Open the folder that contains template.yaml.

What does this mean? Do I have to setup a new SAM application or can I just configure my existing lambda to work like this? What does template.yaml need to contain?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [this](https://github.com/bespoken/bstpy) a while back (I assume you code in Python).

This will expose your lambda as an http endpoint locally. Then you can use tools like [Bespoken Proxy](https://bespoken.io) or [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) to put the endpoint on the public internet. Just use it as a normal url for Alexa.